# How to get rid of slight white border on the corners of this input in chrome (code sandbox included)?

Tags: css, google-chrome

[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-hooks-uv1gq?file=/src/styles.css

I am trying to do dark mode but there is this very slight white border in the corners of the input on chrome... any ideas what this is?

Comment: It's coming from the focus styling. Why is this focus styling needed? The box-shadow is hiding it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

this is for focus styling of input, you can add

```
input:focus {
   background: unset
}
```